# Instead of selecting into a table and then selecting from that table: what is a better way to join?

Tags: t-sql

So, in my queries, I've had the need to restructure some data.

To do this--I have created select statements that select some set into a table that before hand, I checked if it existed and then dropped the table if it did.
These tables are repopulated everytime I have to run an SSIS package and I feel like if I keep going down this path--things will get messy.

Is there a way to select out of a select statement in the middle of a select statement?

```
Select Field1
,Field2
,Field3

,SELECT DISTINCT R.Field4
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT
    L.Open_DT
    ,L.Group_NPI
    , bil.*
    ,Row_Number() over (partition by group_npi order by L.open_dt) AS RNK
FROM tbl_Location L
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [MOAD].[dbo].[qry_Location_Address_Billing] bil
        ON L.Location_ID = bil.Location_ID
) AS R
WHERE Rnk = 1 AND Location_ID IS NOT NULL AS Field4,

,Field5
,Field6
From Tables
```

I've edited this question in attempts to clarify.

I want it to come out like so:

```
Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4 (from that nested query), Field5, Field6
```

Comment: Example table schema and illustrative data, along with your expected output would be helpful in clarifying the question.

Comment: your question is not clear. Try and explain it a bit more.

Comment: @MEdwin I tried to clarify.

Comment: @3N1GM4 I tried to clarify :)

Comment: You can `join` `Tables` with that `sub select`?

Comment: What’s the relationship between the records in your R query (where Field4 is coming from) and records from ‘Tables’? How do you know which Field4 values go with which records from ‘Tables’?

Comment: they would have a related key.  (Group_NPI is a number)
Is this an inner join situation?  I just don't know how to make them connect.

Comment: an image is starting to appear in my brain.... would I just have that query down below, treat it as a table? and then join on the query?  give it an alias?

Comment: Really what we need to see to be able to help you is the exact schema of the tables involved, with example data and your expected output. It should then be simple to explain how to build the query you need.

Comment: For example, you have several fields from the tables aliased as `L` and `bil` included in your subquery, but you never define which of them should be used to construct or derive `Field4`. If you can show us some sample data (even if it is not real data, but just values you have made up to illustrate) from all 3 tables you mention, as well as the results you would expect from your query based on this data, we will be able to help you.